# Why did this WhatsApp message freeze my phone?

Tags: text-editors, code, whatsapp

> Warning☠
>   If you touch this box, [ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏ ‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎ ] your phone will hang.
>   You were warned.

My friend sent me the above message and when I touched in between the square box my phone really hanged.  What caused this to happen?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus: This question is actually answerable.  The "box" does contain some funky garbage that may be interesting to look at.

Comment: The question may well be answerable, but it is off-topic. If it is an Android phone problem then [android.se], for iPhones there is [apple.se] or for Windows Phone there is [windowsphone.se]. The question does not make clear where it belongs but as per the help centre smartphones are off-topic.

Comment: Too long by 1410 characters. XD. See this https://imgur.com/2M5qZD5

Comment: @C0deDaedalus:  Why did you post a picture of this question?

Comment: @Scott, Look at the bottom of picture carefully. You will see the message that I got when I copy pasted `message in OP` illustrating, something wrong in the message.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.   It would have been much clearer if you had just said that the message contains a large number of invisible characters.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Tom Scott just made a video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jC4NNUYIIdM Nice timing :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "box" in your text snippet contains these Unicode characters that repeat a bunch of times:

- [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (U+200E)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm)
- [RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (U+200F)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm)

There are ordinary spaces interspersed to give the box some width.

These marks, called [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), don't take up any width and are practically invisible.  **Your mobile phone and/or the app involved probably got stuck because it couldn't process all these control characters used in this unexpected way.**

Here's what the text looks like to Vim:

[image: garbage]

And `hexdump` shows:

```
deltik@node51 [/tmp]$ hexdump -C garbage.txt 
00000000  57 61 72 6e 69 6e 67 f0  9f 9a a7 e2 98 a0 f0 9f  |Warning.........|
00000010  9a a7 0a 49 66 20 79 6f  75 20 74 6f 75 63 68 20  |...If you touch |
00000020  74 68 69 73 20 62 6f 78  2c 20 5b 20 e2 80 8e e2  |this box, [ ....|
00000030  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000040  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000050  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000060  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000070  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000080  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000090  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000000a0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000000b0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000000c0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000000d0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000000e0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000000f0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000100  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000110  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000120  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000130  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000140  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000150  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000160  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000170  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000180  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000190  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000001a0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000001b0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000001c0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000001d0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000001e0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000001f0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000200  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000210  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000220  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000230  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000240  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000250  8e 20 e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |. ..............|
00000260  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000270  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000280  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000290  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000002a0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000002b0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000002c0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000002d0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000002e0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000002f0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000300  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000310  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000320  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000330  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000340  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000350  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000360  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000370  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000380  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000390  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000003a0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000003b0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000003c0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000003d0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000003e0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000003f0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000400  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000410  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000420  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000430  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000440  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000450  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000460  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000470  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000480  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000490  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000004a0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e 20  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |....... ........|
000004b0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000004c0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000004d0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000004e0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000004f0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000500  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000510  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000520  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000530  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000540  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000550  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000560  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000570  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000580  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000590  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000005a0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000005b0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000005c0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000005d0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000005e0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000005f0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000600  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000610  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000620  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000630  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000640  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000650  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000660  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000670  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000680  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000690  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000006a0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000006b0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000006c0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000006d0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000006e0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000006f0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e 20 e2 80  |............. ..|
00000700  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000710  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000720  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000730  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000740  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000750  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000760  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000770  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000780  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000790  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000007a0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000007b0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000007c0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000007d0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000007e0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000007f0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000800  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000810  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000820  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000830  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000840  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000850  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000860  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000870  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000880  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000890  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000008a0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000008b0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000008c0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000008d0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000008e0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000008f0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000900  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000910  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000920  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000930  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000940  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000950  e2 80 8e 20 e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |... ............|
00000960  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000970  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000980  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000990  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000009a0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000009b0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000009c0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
000009d0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
000009e0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
000009f0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000a00  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000a10  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000a20  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000a30  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000a40  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000a50  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000a60  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000a70  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000a80  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000a90  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000aa0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000ab0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000ac0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000ad0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000ae0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000af0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000b00  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000b10  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000b20  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000b30  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000b40  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000b50  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000b60  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000b70  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000b80  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000b90  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000ba0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e 20 e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |......... ......|
00000bb0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000bc0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000bd0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000be0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000bf0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000c00  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000c10  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000c20  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000c30  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000c40  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000c50  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000c60  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000c70  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000c80  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000c90  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000ca0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000cb0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000cc0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000cd0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000ce0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000cf0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000d00  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000d10  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000d20  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000d30  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000d40  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000d50  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000d60  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000d70  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000d80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000d90  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000da0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000db0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000dc0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000dd0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000de0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000df0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e 20  |............... |
00000e00  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000e10  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000e20  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000e30  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000e40  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000e50  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000e60  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000e70  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000e80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000e90  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000ea0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000eb0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000ec0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000ed0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000ee0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000ef0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000f00  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000f10  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000f20  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000f30  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000f40  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000f50  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000f60  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000f70  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000f80  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000f90  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000fa0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000fb0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000fc0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00000fd0  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
00000fe0  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  |................|
00000ff0  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80  |................|
00001000  8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2  80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f  |................|
… truncated …
000016c0  8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2  80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e  |................|
000016d0  e2 80 8f e2 80 8e e2 80  8f e2 80 8e e2 80 8f e2  |................|
000016e0  80 8e e2 80 8f e2 80 8e  e2 80 8f e2 80 8e 20 5d  |.............. ]|
000016f0  20 79 6f 75 72 20 70 68  6f 6e 65 20 77 69 6c 6c  | your phone will|
00001700  20 68 61 6e 67 2e 0a 59  6f 75 20 77 65 72 65 20  | hang..You were |
00001710  77 61 72 6e 65 64 2e 0a                           |warned..|
00001718
```